# Convert lit file into mobi

Tags: conversion, mobi

I want to know how I can convert a lit file into a mobi (or alternatively a searchable pdf).

I've tried the online services, and Calibre doesn't even open it.

I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

"LIT files contain the actual contents of the eBook and DRM (Digital Rights Management) protection...", from [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/366643/what-is-a-lit-file-and-how-do-i-open-one/). Likely, DRM is preventing opening an unlicensed copy.

Though there are ways to defeat DRM or [remove it](https://www.howtogeek.com/162994/how-to-strip-the-drm-from-your-kindle-ebooks-for-cross-device-enjoyment-and-archiving/), the legality of doing so is questionable. Do you have a right to remove DRM for your own e-books, which you've purchased? And is anyone looking at what you do?  Read [*Adobe is Spying on Users, Collecting Data on Their eBook Libraries*](https://the-digital-reader.com/2014/10/06/adobe-spying-users-collecting-data-ebook-libraries/), for example.